# How find URL browsing time duration in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Here is the image of my record table, I want URL and date group, find that URL first time and last calculated time duration of the URL

Please anyone help me, I am a new SQL query builder

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here are attached table screenshot

Comment: If you can, do not add the image as a link. Someday the link will stop working and your question, however best it may be, will become useless. Add graphics as image or code as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for simple group by for URL, DATE combination, as given below:

```sql
SELECT URL, DATE, min(Time) as URLFirstTime, max(Time) as URLLastTime
FROM gunageorge.BrowserHistory
GROUP BY URL,DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't detailed in your request, I have interpreted that you would the max DateTime for the same URL:

```html
select URl, max(DataOra)
from (select    url,
      convert(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [Data], 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), [ora], 108)) as DataOra
      from gunageorge.BrowserHistory) as a
group by URL
```

Comment: Javascript snippets do not work (and therefore shouldn't be used) on SQL.